# Non-value field is accessed in 'hashCode()'

Tags: scala, overriding, hashcode

It happen with id. (Non-value field is accessed in 'hashCode()')

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Date

case class Category() {
    var id: Integer = _
    var parentId: Integer = _
    var name: String = _
    var status: Boolean = _
    var sortOrder: Integer = _
    var createTime: Date = _
    var updateTime: Date = _

    def this(id: Integer, parentId: Integer, name: String, status: Boolean, sortOrder: Integer, createTime: Date, updateTime: Date) {
        this()
        this.id = id
        this.parentId = parentId
        this.name = name
        this.status = status
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder
        this.createTime = createTime
        this.updateTime = updateTime
    }

    override def hashCode(): Int = {
        if (id != null) id.hashCode() else 0
    }
}
```

If I change `var id` to `val id`, it will be ok. But I need setter, I cant't set it as a val.

Comment: Your `hashCode()` method works for me (Scala 2.12.2). It is very, **very**, bad Scala, but it compiles and runs. (I did have to change the name of the `this()` method.)

Comment: @jwvh Lol, I'm a beginner of scala~ Can you check my answer, it is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I try many times, I think this should be a good choice.
Any ideas?

```
override def hashCode(): Int = {
    if (getId != null) getId.hashCode() else 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Non value field in `hashCode` means you're relaying on a mutable field to generate the classes hashcode, which may be dangerous, depending how you use that class. For example, assume you have a `HashMap[Category, String]`, you place an entry in the hash map and them mutate the `id` field, now that hashmap can no longer find the class instance by it's hashcode.

You're treating a case class like it's a regular, mutable Java class. Case classes provides the mechanism of encapsulating *immutable* data in a syntax convenient way (where you also get a few nice things for free, such as `hashCode`, `equals`, etc). What you can do is make your case class accept parameters via it's primary constructor:

```
case class Category(id: Int,
                    parentId: Int,
                    name: String,
                    status: Boolean,
                    sortOrder: Int,
                    createTime: Date,
                    updateTime: Date) {
  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode()
}
```

If you want to update `Category`, you can use the utility `copy` method defined on a case class:

```
val cat = Category(id = 1,
                   parentId = 1,
                   name = "Hello",
                   status = true,
                   sortOrder = 1,
                   createTime = new Date(123132123L),
                   updateTime = new Date(52234234L))

val newCat: Category = cat.copy(id = 2)
```

Another way of approaching this (which I like less TBH) would be to make all your fields an `Option[T]` with a default value set to `None`:

```
case class Category(id: Option[Int] = None,
                    parentId: Option[Int] = None,
                    name: Option[String] = None,
                    status: Option[Boolean] = None,
                    sortOrder: Option[Int] = None,
                    createTime: Option[Date] = None,
                    updateTime: Option[Date] = None) {
  override def hashCode(): Int = id.map(_.hashCode()).getOrElse(0)
}
```

And then updating them once you can populate the class with data:

```
val cat = Category()
val newCat = cat.copy(id = Some(1))
```

Comment: But in somewhere I need to `new Category()`. I need a non-parameter constructor.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Can you elaborate on what that means? Why do you need to new an instance without any fields?

Comment: I'm building a javaweb. In some method I need to return a category object which I just need to set 2 parameters.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier See my updated answer (second part), perhaps that's more in tune with what you need. In general though, if you only need to set two fields, why not create a case class with two fields?

Comment: Actually, it is a POJO many place need it. In other method, maybe need 3 or 4 parameters.  : )

Comment: @AurevoirXavier It's a POJO you've written in Scala?

Comment: I'm new here. I want to build springmvc project with scala. I saw some projects and some people suggest me create the POJO as case class.